# Not able to save values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I am able to see that data is received for the ticker but i am not able to write it to pandas file `df`.

```py
stock_data = []
with open('Nifty 50 Scrapped data.csv') as csvfile:
    stockticker_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in stockticker_data:
        print(row)

        for ticker in row:
            stock_data.append(web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '1/1/2018', '1/1/2019'))
            # stock_data.append(all_data)
            df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data)
            print(df)
```

if i `print(stock_data)` instead of `print(df)` i get the following output:

```
['ASIANPAINT.NS']
[                   High          Low  ...     Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                        
2018-01-01  1165.000000  1138.099976  ...   591349.0  1129.451782
2018-01-02  1150.000000  1134.050049  ...   516171.0  1128.562866
2018-01-03  1149.000000  1135.300049  ...   593809.0  1127.723511
2018-01-04  1178.000000  1145.900024  ...   729965.0  1157.499146
2018-01-05  1192.000000  1167.449951  ...  1151320.0  1170.535278
...                 ...          ...  ...        ...          ...
2018-12-27  1384.750000  1354.300049  ...  2174090.0  1365.134155
2018-12-28  1383.000000  1359.000000  ...  1705033.0  1358.669067
2018-12-31  1378.000000  1367.300049  ...   698593.0  1365.681274
2019-01-01  1379.699951  1358.599976  ...   664707.0  1364.189331
2019-01-02  1386.849976  1361.599976  ...  1233780.0  1375.876221

[248 rows x 6 columns]]
['AXISBANK.NS']
[                   High          Low  ...     Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                        
2018-01-01  1165.000000  1138.099976  ...   591349.0  1129.451782
2018-01-02  1150.000000  1134.050049  ...   516171.0  1128.562866
2018-01-03  1149.000000  1135.300049  ...   593809.0  1127.723511
2018-01-04  1178.000000  1145.900024  ...   729965.0  1157.499146
2018-01-05  1192.000000  1167.449951  ...  1151320.0  1170.535278
...                 ...          ...  ...        ...          ...
2018-12-27  1384.750000  1354.300049  ...  2174090.0  1365.134155
2018-12-28  1383.000000  1359.000000  ...  1705033.0  1358.669067
2018-12-31  1378.000000  1367.300049  ...   698593.0  1365.681274
2019-01-01  1379.699951  1358.599976  ...   664707.0  1364.189331
2019-01-02  1386.849976  1361.599976  ...  1233780.0  1375.876221
```

This is which i want but the output of             `df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data)` `print(df)` is

```
['ASIANPAINT.NS']
                                                   0
0                     High          Low  ...     ...
['AXISBANK.NS']
                                                   0
0                     High          Low  ...     ...
1                    High         Low  ...    Vol...
['BAJAJ-AUTO.NS']
                                                   0
0                     High          Low  ...     ...
1                    High         Low  ...    Vol...
2                     High          Low  ...    V...
```

Why is the data not showing here?

Comment: What is the return value of `web.get_data_yahoo`? It looks like it may be a dataframe already.

Comment: @ChrisHeald yes it is a dataframe but it gets rewritten after every iteration so i need to append that to another variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stock_data = []
with open('Nifty 50 Scrapped data.csv') as csvfile:
    stockticker_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in stockticker_data:
        print(row)

        for ticker in row:
            stock_data.append(web.get_data_yahoo(ticker,'1/1/2018','1/1/2019'))
            # stock_data.append(all_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data)
print(df)
```

try this maybe that loop messes up your df

Comment: I tried that already by that just prints the `row` in `stockticker_data` but does not contain the data from yahoo. ['ASIANPAINT.NS']
['AXISBANK.NS']
['BAJAJ-AUTO.NS']
['BAJFINANCE.NS']
['BAJAJFINSV.NS']